# MYSQL trigger is not working after CSV import

Tags: mysql, csv, triggers

I've created trigger, which should automatically set foreign key, from tables "restaurants" by unique name field.
Code:

```
create trigger `link_with_restaurant` before insert on `categories`
for each row begin
    declare uid text;
    select id into uid from restaurants where name=NEW.restaurant_name;
    set NEW.restaurant_id = uid;
end;
```

When I'm testing it manually it works, but when I try to import data from CSV file, trigger is not working. Here is screenshot with command flow:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPD:
Problem was really in restaurant_name column, mysql gives very strange output:
[image]

I also tried to add following line inside my trigger:

```
    set NEW.restaurant_name = trim(NEW.restaurant_name);
```

But it didnt work...

My CSV file is really simple.
[image]

Comment: Is there a row in `restaurants` where the name is 'KFC'? Have you double-checked that?

Comment: Just look at the picture - I inserted category with restaurant_name KFC and restaurant_id was set automatically...

Comment: Have you confirmed there is no unexpected white-space in your CSV file? (e.g. "KFC " in the CSV would behave differently than "KFC" in your `insert`) Maybe include the line from the CSV in your question.

Comment: Yes, a trailing white-space would not be visible in the client output. You can check: `SELECT CONCAT('[', restaurant_name, ']') AS bracketed_name FROM categories;`

Comment: From your update, it looks like MySQL might be taking your newline character as part of the KFC entry (not sure why your `trim` attempt wouldn't fix that, though). How was your CSV file generated and on what OS? Do you know for sure lines are terminated by `\n`, not `\r\n` (you are explicitly setting this when loading it)? Maybe try quoting KFC or removing the line break to confirm that is the issue.